# Can i use different payment method for in-app subscription in google play / apple store?

Tags: paypal, in-app-purchase, google-play, app-store, in-app-billing

i see many applications downloaded from google play that offer different alternative payment method like

- cell phone bill
- google Wallet
- Credit card
- Paypal

Do we have the right to offer in google play several distinct payment method for in-app subscription ? the problem is that i don't like that google take 30% of fees when it's me who send the user on the play store to simply download my application.

Same question about apple store ..

below a screen copy of well know social application named badoo that i download from the play store and who offer several distinct alternative payment :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With Google Play it depends on the app and the in-app product you are selling.

> - Developers offering products within a game downloaded on Google Play or providing access to game content must use Google Play In-app Billing as the method of payment.
> - Developers offering products within another category of app downloaded on Google Play must use Google Play In-app Billing as the method of payment, except for the following cases:
>
>   - Payment is solely for physical products
>   - Payment is for digital content that may be consumed outside of the app itself (e.g. songs that can be played on other music players).

https://play.google.com/about/monetization.html#payments

If I have to guess, it may be that badoo satisfies the last point; that their digital content can be consumed outside of the app.

iTunes, however is not relaxed on this point at all:

> **11.2** Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies

If you want further clarification, I suggest asking Apple and Google. They are the only ones who can tell you if your app will be rejected or not.

Come back here and answer your question if you get clarification, this question has been asked many times before and it will be helpful to others who are also unsure.

Comment: Thanks marc for this answer! To clarify the exemple of badoo, it's a online dating website, and the subscription is mostly to buy extra options like "incognito mode" or "boost my profile in search result". I don't see how the subscription can be consumed outside of the application (except that they also have a website and an ios application where the subscription will apply too). About asking google, i already send 3 messages to them and still receive no explanations why such app offer different payment method :(

Comment: I guess all you can do then is try to submit submit the app. If you haven't built the other payment methods yet, perhaps implement the simplest option first. If that gets through, add another, etc. If it doesn't get through you can argue that badoo do it and see where that gets you. It will help if you do indeed have other ways of consuming the content, ios, web, etc.